# Install haskell-mode failed via el-get-install

Tags: haskell-mode

`el-get` manage my other packages properly and easily, so I tried to install `haskell-mode` by `el-get-install`; however, it failed:

```
sed -e 's/@@GIT_VERSION@@/13.10-301-g6e48791/g;s/@GIT_VERSION@/13.10-301-g6e48791/g;s/@@VERSION@@/13.10/g;s/@VERSION@/13.10/g' < haskell-mode.el > haskell-mode.tmp.el

In toplevel form:
haskell-mode.tmp.el:316:8:Error: Wrong type argument: sequencep, end
make: *** [haskell-mode.elc] Error 1
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: This likely should be reported here: https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/issues/new.

Comment: @tarsius Thank you for pointing me the report link. I've reported. https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/issues/2044

Answer (score 1):

This was an [upstream bug](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/403) that has been fixed in the meantime.